# Queria saber como faço pra conectar os dados do banco com os dados do gráfico no Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Eu não faço ideia de como vou fazer para manipular os dados, até agora o que eu tentei realizar foi esse código:

```
public void loadChart()
{
        MySqlConnection conexao = new MySqlConnection();
        conexao.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=db_softaurus;Uid=root;Pwd=usbw;";
        conexao.Open();
        string Query = "select genero_animal, Count(1) as Total  from tb_animal group by genero_animal";
        MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conexao);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;
        try
        {
            myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                chart1.Series["Macho"].Points.AddXY(myReader.GetString("genero_animal"));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }`
```

Eu queria retornar o sexo do animal separado por macho e femea no gráfico

Comment: Não entendi, exatamente, qual é a sua dúvida? qual é o erro apresentado?

Comment: Então, eu queria exibir no gráfico a quantidade de animais do gênero macho e do gênero fêmea, porém eu não faço ideia de como fazer isso, eu tentei fazer com esse código mas, não deu muito certo

Comment: Você pode começar alterando a sua query, tirando o `Where genero_animal = 'M'` e substituindo por `select genero_animal, Count(1) as Total, from tb_animal Group By genero_animal`

Comment: No caso aqui deu erro de Syntax

Comment: É que agora você precisa alterar o resto do código...

Comment: Consegui. o que eu faço agora?

Comment: Depende, o que você fez? Edite a pergunta, atualizando o seu progresso.

Comment: Alterei a query, porém não sei o que devo fazer para conseguir inserir esses dados da query no gráfico

Answer (score 0):

Levando em consideração o `Enum` abaixo e que você queira exibir apenas os totais por gênero, você pode seguir o exemplo abaixo.

```
public enum GeneroEnum
{
    Macho  = 'M',
    Femea = 'F'

}
```

**Código**

```
MySqlConnection conexao = new MySqlConnection();
conexao.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=db_softaurus;Uid=root;Pwd=usbw;";
conexao.Open();
string Query = "select genero_animal, Count(1) as total  from tb_animal group by genero_animal";
MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conexao);
MySqlDataReader myReader;

try
{
    //remove as colunas pré configuradas ao adicionar o componente
    chart1.Series.Clear();

    myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
    while (myReader.Read())
    {
        //identificando o nome da coluna
        var serie = Enum.GetName(typeof(GeneroEnum), myReader.GetChar("genero_animal")).ToString();
        
        //adicionando a nova coluna
        chart1.Series.Add(serie);

        chart1.Series[serie].Points.AddXY(0, myReader.GetInt32("total"));

    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

**Exemplo**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Funcionouu, muito obrigado cara!

Comment: @EnzodaCostaXavier Se a reposta resolveu o seu problema, você deve votar nela e aceitar como a conclusão do problema